Unable to remove input box border in React
I've been trying to remove the black box that appears when you click the input box, but it doesn not go away
  const renderSearch = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.searchSection}>
        <FaSearch style={styles.searchIcon} />
        <TextInput
          value={searchValue}
          onChangeText={(text) => onSearch(text)}
          placeholder="Search for a restaurant"
          style={styles.input}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    color: '#424242',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderWidth: 0, // Eliminar el borde
    padding: 0, // Eliminar el relleno
    fontSize: 16 // Ajustar el tamaño de la fuente según sea necesario
  },

Remove the black box

Please see https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines.

Are you referring to outline? The border that appears when you focus on the input.
If so, try adding this css in your input:
  outline: none;

